# Create complex rules in infopath form

Tags: infopath-rules

I have an infopath form with two dropdown lists and depending on the vaues I have to choose the value in another third dropdown list, I have 40 possible combinations and I don't want to create 40 rules to rule the final dropdown list, there is a logic like a switch condition like in programaming c#?

Comment: Can you please close your previous questions, if they have been answered..

Comment: please tell me how I can close them.

Comment: I guess you figured it out :)

Comment: still I don't know how to close them.

Comment: Just mark the tick to close the question.. you already did :)

Comment: I dont see the close option, I see share, edit, delete or flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'switch' or 'case/select' command in InfoPath.  If you want to avoid a multitude of rules, you can set up a SharePoint list with the possible combinations in two columns and the value to retrieve in a third column. Then use a data connection in InfoPath.

Set the query fields of the list to the two values chosen in the dropdowns and then query the data source. If you have multiple matches, you can feed another dropdown with the result. If you have a single match, you can assign it to a field immediately.

Comment: I started doing it as you suggested, but I used a hidden field to make the combinations and avoid having so much dropdowns visibles, thanks.